# Under what specific circumstances can a matrix lose symmetry?

Tags: symmetry

This is a general question: In this [blog post](https://nhigham.com/2021/01/19/what-is-the-nearest-symmetric-matrix/), the author points out that under a unitarily invariant norm, the closest symmetric matrix to the square matrix $M$ is $\frac 1 2 (M + M^T)$. The general question I have is: When might a matrix which ought to be symmetric lose symmetry? I understand *generally* that this may result from rounding errors or sensor errors. The question is: In what *concrete* situations might this happen?

The author suggests some examples but I'd like to see more: *For example, a finite difference approximation to a Hessian matrix can be nonsymmetric even though the Hessian is symmetric. In some cases, lack of symmetry is caused by rounding errors.*

These examples are rather vague though.

Comment: What are sensor errors? // Transforming the matrix can introduce floating point errors that are not symmetric, like tridiagonalization or generally transforms $Q^TMQ$.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Any error that comes from physical sensors failing to read a physical value correctly, or failing to follow an idealised model. Essentially, anything that isn't the result of errors from floating point or fixed point. I don't know what the correct terminology is.

Comment: I don't understand the question. The identity matrix is symmetric, and it always will be. It doesn't just "lose symmetry", sitting as a printed $I$ on the page. You have to describe what processes act on the object for the question to make sense.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth A matrix can lose symmetry for instance because of floating point errors, with explicit examples by Lutz.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth The matrix clearly must arise from physical measurement or from the output of a computation, or some combination of these. This rules out your identity matrix example.

Comment: Then you're doing it wrong. If you know the matrix is symmetric, and you compute separate updates to $A_{ij}$ and $A_{ji}$, then that's just not how it should be done. You should add half of the updates to each of $A_{ij}$ and $A_{ji}$ at the same time.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth You appear to be describing the transformation $M \mapsto \frac 1 2 (M + M^T)$. When might this need to be done?

Comment: If you know that the matrix should be symmetric, and if the symmetry is an important property to you, and yet you're independently updating entries, then you're doing it wrong.

Comment: This kind of symmetrization is commonly performed in primal-dual methods for semidefinite programming.

Comment: I will re-state my concern with the question: A matrix is either symmetric, or it is not. It doesn't "lose" this property. A statement such as "a matrix can lose symmetry because of floating point errors" makes no sense to me: "Symmetry of a matrix" is a statement about it's *state*; "loosing symmetry" is a statement about a *process*, i.e., a transition from one state to another. You have to describe what these processes are, i.e., what are you starting from and what kinds of operations you are applying.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth I suppose I'm asking where nearly symmetric matrices show up, where by "nearly symmetric" I mean that $||M - \frac 1 2 (M + M^T) || < \varepsilon$ for some small $\varepsilon$, and where the adjustment $M \leftarrow \frac 1 2 (M + M^T)$ might need to be carried out.